# I cannot find the file 'my.cnf ' to change 'bind-adress' to allow remote managing of MySQL database

Tags: mysql, remote

I want to update some data to a MySQL remote server.  I have conexion between the server and the client through VPN and it works. But I can't manage server's databases from the client. I've read that I need to modify the file 'my.cnf' and write in 'bind-adress' Client's IP. That's correct?? I can not find this file in the server. I'm using windows 7 in both machines and I have installed MySQL server 5.5. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure bind-address has anything to do with this? Seems like an option to specify what addresses your server will be listening on, which would definitely not be your client's IP.

Comment: I've read it in some forums. the people have solved this problem, changing the bind adress for 127.0.0.1 (mysql interface) or client's IP. However, most of them uses Lynux. The point is Mysql server is configured to don't allow external management, I should reconfigure something. I thougth that was bin-adress

Comment: It is, but you need to read the man pages again. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address will tell you how to set it up. Essentially you want your server to listen on its external interfaces as well as the loopback in order for your client to be able to connect.

Comment: Also you might have to change the allowed hosts of the username you are going to be logging in with (normally they are set to localhost or 127.0.0.1 since the web server often runs on the same machine as the database for small scale deployments)

Comment: No problem, make sure to mark my answer as accepted if you find the file and the parameter worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can find information [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/Find-a-file-or-folder) about searching for files in Windows 7. Simply use 'my.cnf' as the file name and you will know where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for it in the folder where you installed MySQL (C:\Program Files\MySQL [version]), or in the subfolder "etc"

If not, check C:\Windows\my.cnf or **my.ini**

If not, check C:\my.cnf

[reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html)